# Is DPAPI usable when only being able to read the file directory?

Tags: encryption, windows, decryption, windows-dpapi

*DPAPI: Windows Data Protection API*

Say I would be able to read a Windows system file system, including all files.
Say there would be a DPAPI encrypted value somewhere in this system that I want to decrypt.
Can I decrypt this value only looking at other files in this file system?

Comment: Is the protected value associated with a user account or a service account?

Comment: Make sure to read https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_Protection_API#Security_properties

Comment: @BenVoigt It is about a chrome cookie blob, which is encrypted with AES-256 using a key stored encrypted with DPAPI. So in a normal case probably a user account.

Comment: Then the user's Windows login password is needed to decrypt the key.

Answer (score 0):

Not for files encrypted to a user, unless you have (or crack) the user's password. DPAPI (either generation) keys are wrapped using a key derived from the user's password, so if you don't have the password, you can't unwrap the user's DPAPI key and can't decrypt anything encrypted with it. (Incidentally, this means if you forcibly reset a user's password - rather than entering the old password and *changing* the user's password - the DPAPI key is lost and data encrypted with it is unrecoverable). I expect the wrapped DPAPI key resides somewhere in the user's registry hive - if not, it's probably somewhere in the SAM hive - but in either way it doesn't matter unless you have the password.

However, if the data is encrypted to the *machine* key rather than to the user, then you may be able to recover it. Microsoft doesn't publish the process for extracting the machine key, for obvious reasons, but I believe it too is stored in the registry, possibly wrapped or at least obfuscated by various other per-install data. The machine key is not user-specific - it only prevents decryption of data that has been removed from the device, by attackers without access to the device - and if you have full access to the file system (meaning there's no disk encryption, or you have the key to that), you can in theory recover it without knowing any other secrets.

Comment: It's a bit more complicated for domain users, since they may have protected data on workstations other than the one where they perform the password change.  But the workstation file system still doesn't contain all the secrets, it needs either the user password or assistance from the AD Domain Controller.